# Add new columns from dictionary stored in another column in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this below on excel sheet:

[image]

I want to add new column called "Name" and display it's values.

I have tried this approach but it is only showing me "NA" values

```
#1 Method1
df['Name'] = df['Columns'].str['name']

#2 Method2
df['Name'] = df['Columns'].get('name')

#3 Method3
df['Name'] = df['Columns'].str.get('name')
```

Is there any way I can create a new column based on these conditions?

Answer (score 0):

If missing values it means ther are no dictionaries in column, but strings, you can convert them by `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast

df['Name'] = df['Columns'].apply(ast.literal_eval).str.get('name')
```